# NSNumber and NSTimeInterval

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to get the system time in milliseconds.
 For that I have declared:

```
 NSNumber *createdTimeInMilliSec; //in class declaration
```

and in one of my instance functions, I doing:

```
 self.createdTimeInMilliSec= ([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]*1000); //ERROR: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setCreatedTimeInMilliSec:'
```

`timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` returns in `NSTimeInterval`, so how to convert that into `NSNumber`? Or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`NSTimeInterval` is typedefed as follow : `typedef double NSTimeInterval;`.

To create a `NSNumber` with, use :

```
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:yourTimeIntervalValue];
```

Comment: `NSNumber *n = @(yourTimeIntervalValue);` works too, and looks prettier.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's clear from the other answers - but NSTimeInterval is actually just a typedef'ed double. You can get an NSNumber from it by doing `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:timeInterval]` or even more succinctly `@(timeInterval)`.

Answer (score 1):

[NSTimeInterval](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW69) is a typedef for a double. So use `NSNumber`'s convenience constructor `numberWithDouble:` as follows:

```
self.createdTimeInMilliSec= [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]*1000)];
```

Answer (score 1):

As NSTimeInterval is a double, you could do

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: myTimeInterval];
```